# The number game

Tags: mathematics, number-property

> There is a number,
> the second digit of which is smaller than the first digit by $4$, and if the number was divided by the digits' sum, the quotient would be $7$.

What is this number.

Comment: The hint it leaves only 6 possible numbers.  That is superfluous imho.

Comment: @FlorianF Please tell me a better hint then. I didn't find one.

Comment: I would say the problem is already easy enough.  No hint needed.

Comment: @FlorianF Ok. edited.

Comment: I think it was better to mention that the number has two digits in total.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is another answer

> For number AB:
>
>
> 1. A - B = 4
> 2. (10A + B) ÷ (A + B) = 7
>
>
> Rearrange 1. to A = B + 4
>
>
> Substitute A into 2. -> (10[B + 4] + B) ÷ ([B + 4] + B) = 7
>
>
> Simplify 2.
>  - (10B + 40 + B) ÷ (2B + 4) = 7
>  - 11B + 40 = 14B + 28
>  - 12 = 3B
>  - B = 4
>
>
> A = B + 4 = 8
>
>
> Number is 84

Comment: @math Thanks. How do you use the spoiler feature?

Comment: Visit [spoilers in editing-help](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/editing-help#spoilers "spoiler")

Answer (score 1):

After some guess and check, the answer is,

> 84

Since

> 8 - 4 = 4
>  84 / 12 = 7

Comment: Assuming that "second digit" and "first digit" are counted from left, it is actually possible to prove that this is the unique answer, even without the hint.

Comment: It’s an algebra problem. The answer added by @asg gives the steps.